# Replacing "product name" with "Item + productId" when product is added in Magento via admin panel

Tags: magento, title

I want to auto generate product names in Magento.

When I'm going to add a product, for the product name I will type some string.
When I save the product, I want the product name to be automatically generated such that the *product name* becomes **Item."productId"**.

Comment: How are you creating these products? Through the Admin panel? API? Import? And, just because I'm curious, *why?*

Comment: Hi @benmarks, thanks for the answer.
The products will be added from the Admin panel.
This change will save a lot of time. The products are lot and in my case it's not effectively to create title for each one.
I hope you understand me.
Jordan.

Comment: Why not create one, export using System > Import/Export, then do this in CSV?

Comment: Thanks for the proposal, but if we can change INSERT QUERY to out needs after saving - it will be great.

Comment: And you want the product id from the database, the autoincrement value from the catalog_product_entity table, not the SKU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I want to thanks to all users which write in the topic. Thanks a lot of guys!

I did it, but I make it easier. (because I have very basic knowledge in Magento and it would toke more time)

So... With my colegues decided to make it with php/jquery/ajax.

First we create one single php file, which return **the last id**:

```
 <?php
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
 require_once 'app/Mage.php';
 umask(o);
 Mage::app('default');
 Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));

$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); //getting product model
$collection = $model->getCollection(); //products collection
foreach ($collection as $product) //loop for getting products
{                    
    $id=$product->getId();
}
if($id)echo $id+1; //id of product
else{
    echo 0;
}
?>
```

After step one I set the value of input (i.e. I auto generate the name):

```
if($j('#name').val()=='' &&  window.location.href.indexOf("admin/catalog_product/new/") > -1) {
    $j.post('http://www.website.com/file.php', function(data) {
        $j('#name').val('Item №'+data);
    }); 
}
```

Thanks again for help.

Best Regards,
Jordan!

Answer (score 4):

Answering assuming that OP wants to incorporate the auto-increment value from the entity table into business data. This is generally not a great idea.

This is an interesting task which can be easily accomplished with Magento's EAV implementation  - particularly when working in the catalog module. First, some background.

When an EAV entity is saved, it has a nice, neat array of key => value pairs which represent the attributes and attribute values for that entity:

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product->_data['attribute_code'] = 'attribute value';
```

During the save process, the EAV resource model takes this array and iterates over it. For each attribute, identified by its code (`attribute_code` in the above example) and its entity (`catalog_product` in the case of products), the configuration for the attribute itself is loaded. Of particular importance is the "backend model" for an attribute, as it is invoked to do pre- and post-processing of/relating to the value.

In the current case, there is a piece of information which will not be present when we are saving the attribute, at least, not in a way in which we can use it: the new product id. This can be used to adjust the original value as part of the save process.

It's always nice to have an example from the core, so, refer to the `price` attribute and its backend model, `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Price` which can be seen in the `eav_attribute` table:

```
SELECT `attribute_code`, `backend_model`
FROM `eav_attribute`
LEFT JOIN `eav_entity_type` USING (`entity_type_id`)
WHERE `attribute_code` = 'price';

#+----------------+-----------------------------------------+
#| attribute_code | backend_model                           |
#+----------------+-----------------------------------------+
#| price          | catalog/product_attribute_backend_price |
#+----------------+-----------------------------------------+
#1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

When a product is saved, the price attribute's backend_model is instantiated and (in this case) the [`afterSave()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Price.php#L75) method is called. Incidentally, this method is what updates pricing by conversion rate for website-scoped pricing. This same approach can be used to modify the `name` attribute.

The following setup script will add the backend model:

```
<?php

    $installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','default_setup');

    $installer->startSetup();

    $installer->updateAttribute(
        'catalog_product',
        'name',
        'backend_model',
        'custom/product_attribute_backend_name'
    );

    $installer->endSetup();
```

The corresponding `afterSave()` method should do the trick:

```
public function afterSave($object)
{
    $value = $object->getData($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode());
    $origData = $object->getOrigData();
    $origValueExist = $origData && array_key_exists($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode(), $origData);

    //don't do this in case of update
    if ($object->getStoreId() != 0 || !$value || $origValueExist) {
        return $this;
    }

    //append autoinc id
    $newValue = $value .'.'. $object->getId(); // or whatever

    //assume global store, otherwise the stated need is getting weird!
    $object->addAttributeUpdate($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode(), $newValue, 0);

    return $this;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you @benmarks for this fully post.
Can you tell me in which files, I must paste the "backend model" and "afterSave()" method.
Thanks again and in advance.
Jordan.

Comment: This is not a "cut and paste" solution. You need to create a proper Magento module to do this. You need four files: module registration file in *app/etc/modules/*, a module configuration file (*config.xml*), a setup script file in your *sql/...setup/* folder, and the backend model file.

Comment: You can learn a lot here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento

Comment: Thanks again. I will try and if I have questions, I will write.
Thanks again.

Comment: Feel free to update the original question with your work, ad good luck.

Comment: @benmarks great solution. Got a few questions that's a bit out of topic because you took example from `price`. I don't get it what's wrong with updating as it will `return $this` and skip modifying the value. The last one is `$object->addAttributeUpdate()`. I see that it will `setData` with new `value`, save, then `setData` again with `oldvalue`. Why change it back with `oldvalue`?

Comment: @ivantedja It's funky, but for EAV attributes it's the only way (I know of) to hook the save process of a new EAV entity record at the resource level *after* the main record is saved and the entity id is known. If you have another solution, please post it as an answer, as I haven't had to do something like this very often and would be curious to see. Magento almost always has two or more ways to do something.

Comment: @benmarks I do think it is the best solution, I just don't understand the how the `price` code works. Maybe I should create a question for this: `How product's price aftersave works?` as I never touch that area

Comment: @ivantedja - go for it. Quickly, it's used to update price attribute per website based on factor of base currency to website currency.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this from the admin panel product edit screen, you're going to have to remove the "Required" class from the "Name" field so you can save it without the name. This means overriding the Edit form to replace that field specifically. Then you'll have to overload the save-related methods on the product model (or you can do it from the controller), but the child will have to generate the name on save before it goes to the database.

For example:

```
class Module_Catalog_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
{
    protected function _beforeSave()
    {
        parent::_beforeSave();

        $productName = 'Item' . $this->getId();

        if (!$this->getId() && !$this->getName())
        {
            $this->setName('Item Unnamed');

        } elseif ($this->getId()) && strcasecmp($this->getName(), $productName) <> 0)
        {
            $this->setName($productName);
        }
    }
}
```

The only problem with this is that it requires two saves. If you want to have it work on the fly, you'll have to do a second save using the _afterSave() method. Or, once again, you can do it from the controller.

Comment: This issue you mention is that the admin would have to save the product twice, correct?

Comment: @benmarks Yes -- only because on product creation you wouldn't have an ID until after it's inserted into the database.

Comment: @tdlm - ok, wanted to make sure I understood. This was the reason I chose the backend afterSave facility.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Magento Event to do this:

Since Models in Magento have an event prefixes (just take a look at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` and look for `$_eventPrefix`, for our current model the eventPrefix is set to `catalog_product`.

If you now take a look at `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` and search for `_eventPrefix`. You see that eventPrefix are found in _beforeLoad, _afterLoad, _beforeSave, _afterSave and a few others. In these methods you can see an event is dispatched using something as below:

`Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_before', $this->_getEventData());`

This means you have an event available called `catalog_product_save_before`. With this event you can hook into Magento at that time and do your thing, change the field in this case, and Magento handles the rest.

Take a look at http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method for more information how to use these events and turn them into a module. If you don't know how to build modules for Magento and want to learn, there are some awesome on-demand video's for free: http://www.magentocommerce.com/training/on-demand